# Problems with array of type class

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray, foundation

Hey guys I am trying to build a database that maps NSStrings to int. I have on class called Movie.h where each object has a name and a number assigned:

```
//Movie.h
@interface Movie : NSObject
{
    int m_num;
    NSString *m_name;
}
@property int m_num;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *m_name;
@end

//Movie.m
@implementation Movie
@synthesize m_num, m_name;
@end
```

I then have another class called Map where I am implementing functions to play with my "Movies". One of the function is called insert, and it inserts an object of class movie into an array where all movies should be stored. The code compiles but my "m_array" does not seem to keep a record of what I add to it. Here is the code:

```
//Map.h
#import "Movie.h"
@interface Map : NSObject
{
@private
    int m_count;
    NSMutableArray *m_array;
}
@property int m_count;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *m_array;
-(bool) contain: (NSString *) name;
-(bool) insert: (NSString *) name: (int) chap;
@end

//Map.m
@implementation Map
@synthesize m_count, m_array;

//Constructor
-(id) init{
    if (self = [super init]){
        m_count = 0;
    }
    return self;
}
-(bool) contain: (NSString *) name{
    bool b = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_count; i++) {
        Movie *m = [[Movie alloc]init];
        m = [m_array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@ came out in %i", m.m_name, m.m_num);
        if (m.m_name == name) {
            b = true;
        }
    } 
    return b;
}
-(bool) insert:(NSString *) name: (int) chap{
    Movie *m1 = [[Movie alloc]init];
    m1.m_name = name;
    m1.m_num = chap;
    [m_array addObject:m1];
    NSLog(@"Here is the object %@",[m_array objectAtIndex:m_count]);
    m_count++;
    return true;
}
@end

-(bool) upgrade:(NSString *)name :(int)chap{
    if(![self contain:name])
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_count; i++){
        Movie *m = [[Movie alloc]init];
        m = [m_array objectAtIndex:i];
        if(m.m_name == name)
            m.m_num = chap;
    }
    return true;
```

}

Here's my main:

```
//main.m
#import "Map.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool 
    {
        Map *m = [[Map alloc]init];
        [m insert:@"James Bond" :2001];
        if (![m contain:@"James Bond"]) {
            NSLog(@"It does not work");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the console output:

```
2012-02-27 14:20:04.923 myMap[3926:707] Here is the object (null)
2012-02-27 14:20:05.036 myMap[3926:707] (null) came out in 0
2012-02-27 14:20:05.037 myMap[3926:707] It does not work
```

Comment: Why do you have a `m_count` variable? Just use the array's `count` method.

Comment: oh you're right. I'm doing that because I already completed this class in C++, I'm just rewriting the code in objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to create the array:

```
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init]
  if (nil != self) {
    m_count = 0;
    m_array = [NSMutableArray new]; << here
  }
  return self;
}
```

Without creating it, it's just `nil`.

Comment: Thanks! Also is there an easier way to retrieve my object's private member or do I have to do what I do in my insert function, that is create a new movie variable to store in the m_name and m_num in it?

Comment: @user1236187 you're welcome. typically, you would offer a proper initializer (`- (id)initWithNumber:(int)inNumber name:(NSString *)inName`), or sometimes a convenience constructor: `+ (Movie *)newMovieWithNumber:(int)inNumber name:(NSString *)inName { Movie * movie = [Movie new]; movie.number = inNumber; movie.name = inName; return movie; }`. With a proper initializer, the convenience constructor would be just a one-liner.

Comment: and how would I use that if for example, I wanted to upgrade the year assigned to a specific movie? I just posted my "upgrade" function in my first post above.

Comment: Using convenience constructors looks like: `Movie * movie = [Movie newMovieWithNumber:chap name:name];`. note: the program you posted has other issues. as well, the map container is typically implemented using an `NSDictionary`.